# FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, The Person has an Open Enrolment Type Case! Please Close existing case and try again: []

Tags: unit-test

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class TestSMSMSMagicOptOutTrigger {
    static testMethod void SMSMSMagicOpt(){ 
        contact con = new contact();
        //insert con;
        string camRec = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Account' AND Name = 'Person Account' LIMIT 1].id;

        Account a = new Account(FirstName='R1',LastName='A1',SPID__c='test',Gender__c='male',Date_of_Birth__c='01121993',RecordTypeid=camRec);
        insert a;
        Account Acc=new Account(FirstName='Rak',LastName='Al',SPID__c='test1',Gender__c='female',Date_of_Birth__c='01121993',RecordTypeid=camRec,smagicinteract__SMSOptOut__pc = false);
        database.insert(Acc);
        System.debug('error occur'+Acc);
        string camRec1 = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'case' AND Name = 'System Communication Channel Opt-Out Update' LIMIT 1].id;
        case cs = new case(status='close',accountid= acc.id,RecordTypeid=camRec1);
        insert cs;
        acc.SPID__c='0002';
        acc.smagicinteract__SMSOptOut__pc = true;
        update acc;
    }
}
```

Comment: This validation rule is for which Object? Is it for Case or Account? Can you also check from which line the exception is thrown?

Comment: @keerthana chowdhary - it would be helpful if you post the method(s) you are testing as well. From the looks of your test method, you are inserting some accounts then a case and updating an account. There is not assertion or anything, so it's hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish with it. Further, it appears the error in your subject is a validation rule. It would be helpful to know what logic is built out that would trigger that validation error.

Comment: validation rule on  on case object ,  error on (insert cs;)

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about how your environment is structured or what causes your custom validation rule to trigger, there isn't much anyone can assist with.

In order to fix your error, you need to make sure the case you are inserting meets the criteria of the validation rule which fires that exception:

> This error occurs when there is a validation rule and one of the test methods is hitting exception caused by a validation when creating/updating a test record.

[SFDC Help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000002540&language=en_US)